# How to disable logo in Windows 8 metro app live tile?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, live-tile

I am trying to disable the logo in my metro app live tile so that the last line of text in my tile notification will show. The [Windows 8 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868263%28v=win.10%29.aspx)
says that there is a way to disable this logo in the `Package.appxmanifest` file.  However, it does not specify how.  I have set the `ShortName` in my `.appxmanifest` and I have also set the "Show name" field to "All Logos"; however, the default logo still appears in the bottom left-hand corner of the live tile and obscures the last line of text in my tile notification.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A live tile can have an image, text, or no branding.  The default is the app logo, and you override this when you create a live tile update by specifying branding "none", like this:

```
var templateContent = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideImage);
   var imageElement = (XmlElement) templateContent.GetElementsByTagName("image").Item(0);
   imageElement.SetAttribute("src", string.Concat(imagePath, "wide_tile.png"));

   var bindingElement = (XmlElement) templateContent.GetElementsByTagName("binding").Item(0);
   bindingElement.SetAttribute("branding", "none");

   var tile = new TileNotification(templateContent);
   TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both the last line of text and a short name.  It's either logo/shortname or the the last line of text.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d7ed6580-0528-4a28-a475-731b37f2c89b